# How to show collection fields from bcs in infopath list item form?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-2013, bcs

I have a .net assembly business data connector. One of fields is List.
I have external list, based on this connector and InfoPath Item Form for this list item.
I want to show this List as repeating table.
But InfoPath simply ignore this field at all.
Is it possible to achieve? If yes, then how?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I must have a complex property with collection as one of subproperties. In this scenario InfoPath show this property in primary datasource and I can use it in my form.